# Images read from ffmpeg's standard output does sometimes become scrambled. Why?

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, png

I am trying to convert a video into images with ffmpeg, and  then reading these images in a Java program which converts them to a file (that is just for testing, I know ffmpeg can do it too). This works fine for the most part, except that some images become scrambled by ffmpeg and I have no idea why. Is it something wrong with my code, or is it a ffmpeg quirk?

ffmpeg somestimes recover after this strange conversion, while other times it continues to produce garbage. This is how a good and a bad image looks, taken a second in between: [image: Good.][image: Bad.]

This is the code I'm using.

```
process = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpeg, "-i", "C:\myvideo.mpeg", "-r", "1", "-f", "image2pipe", "-c", "png", "-").start();

imageStream = process.getInputStream();

BufferedImage imageBuffer = ImageIO.read(imageStream);

while(imageStream.available() > 0)
{
    try
    {
        imageBuffer = ImageIO.read(imageStream);    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(imageBuffer != null)
    {
        try
        {
            File outputfile = new File("c:\\image.png");
            ImageIO.write(imageBuffer, "png", outputfile);
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I do get some Java stack traces that might give some useful info. They refer to JPEG, although I'm using PNG for output.

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported JPEG process: SOF type 0xc7
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at FilmConverter$1.run(FilmConverter.java:178)

javax.imageio.IIOException: Bogus DQT index 6
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at FilmConverter$1.run(FilmConverter.java:178)

javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported JPEG process: SOF type 0xce
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at FilmConverter$1.run(FilmConverter.java:178)

java.lang.RuntimeException: New BMP version not implemented yet.
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.bmp.BMPImageReader.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.bmp.BMPImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at FilmConverter$1.run(FilmConverter.java:178)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and had a look in FFmpeg's output. Between the actual PNG data, FFmpeg seems to write additional bytes (most times 16 bytes), including the string "END". I'm no expert in the PNG file format, maybe these bytes actually belong to PNG, but ImageIO does not read them. So, the offset of the next PNG image is incorrect and the ImageIO reader runs into problems sooner or later.

A helpful discussion is https://stackoverflow.com/a/13777398/518491 . It states that ImageIO has problems to read multiple images within one stream. It contains a solution for this problem, however without the mentioned additional bytes between the PNG images.

I could solve the problem by doing the following:

1. wrap the FFmpeg output into a BufferedInputStream
2. mark the stream
3. for each image, go to the beginning of the next PNG header, i.e. skip all bytes until you find the PNG header 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A. Reset and skip the stream until it is back on the first byte of the header (0x89)
4. read the image like in the linked post (ImageIO.createImageInputStream, ImageReader, ...)
5. skip all the bytes of the PNG image (getStreamPosition) and again mark the stream
6. continue with step 3

Comment: Using the code in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13777398/1049697 did actually solve the problem for me. Thanks for the great advice!